# No success with inceasing WCF timeout

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

My WCF service runs into a timeout after 60 seconds and I am not able to increase it. I increased all timeouts in web.config and app.config but the result was the same. The service runs on WIN Server 2012 R2 and IIS6, is there any config change I have to do on OS level or on the server itself?

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="600"/>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="svcBehavior">
      <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <!-- Umgeht eine CommunicationException, die auftritt, wenn der ObjectGraph überläuft -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <!-- MTOM Binding für die Übertragung größerer Datenmengen -->
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MTOMBinding"
             messageEncoding="Mtom"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior" name="DBUpdateService.UpdateService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MTOMBinding" contract="DBUpdateService.IDBUpdater" />
  </service>
</services>

<protocolMapping>
  <remove scheme="http" />
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
    Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MTOMBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <!-- Umgeht eine CommunicationException, die auftritt, wenn der ObjectGraph überläuft -->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://10.1.58.48/DBUpdate/UpdateService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MTOMBinding" contract="DBUpdater.IDBUpdater"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IDBUpdater" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Full exception string:
`"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout in IO operation\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.StopTimer()\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   bei System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextRes
ult()\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exception ex)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   bei DBUpdateService.UpdateService.ExecuteReaderUGV(String username, String statement) in c:\\...\\UGV\\DB-Update Service\\trunk\\DBUpdateService\\UpdateService.svc.cs:Zeile 405."`

Line 405 is `ExecuteReader()` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) method.

Comment: Post the full error ToString.

Comment: Exception: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. InnerException: Timeout in IO operation

Comment: That is not the full exception. Post the ToString by editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MySqlException

This timeout has nothing to do with WCF. You can increase WCF limits all you like and the database will still shut you down.

Increase the command timeout in method `ExecuteReaderUGV` or optimize the query.

See what I was able to tell from the exception? This is the first action to debug a problem. Frankly, I feel that you did not read the exception yourself. This is a common mistake. Now you know how to do this yourself in the future.

Comment: By increasing the connection timeout property of the MySQLCommand object the problem was finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

In your server web.config file, try to create a "default" binding, copying your wsHttpBinding binding without a name, like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MTOMBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" ..... />
        <!-- here is the copy withou name -->
        <binding closeTimeout="00:10:00" ..... />
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: No changes... I created a default binding in web.config and app.config but there were no differences.

Comment: You've made all necessary configurations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Hh924831%28v=VS.110%29.aspx
Do you use any other resource in your service that can cause a timeout, like file access or database?

Comment: A database is involved, I'm currently checking that.